# How does iOS delegation actually work?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, delegates, delegation

I understand how to use delegation with iOS objects that already exist. For example, if I create an instance of a UITableView, and my view controller conforms to the UITableView delegate, I can implement the various methods of the UITableView delegate.  My newly create table can receive notifications, for example, when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called.

My question is why did my table get this particular delegate callback?  My understanding is that the delegate is just a list of methods with no implementation. It seems to me there must be a lot more going on. What is really going on "behind the scenes"?

Image if I were to rename all the delegate methods to the following:
- mysteryMethod1
- mysteryMethod2 
- mysteryMethod3... Etc
One of these methods is responsible for setting the height of a row at a particular index. Another one these methods will be responsible for editing a particular row.

Everything I read about delegation says the delegator makes a contract with the delegate. The delegate promises to implement the methods. When it does, somehow everything is wired up correctly and everything magically works. What is the magic that I'm not seeing?

Comment: there are thousands of tutorials which explains how delegate works, one of the random explanations is available e.g. [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/explaining-ios-delegates-a-story-about-your-morning-coffee/).

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to know how delegates actually work you should create your own custom delegate first, that way you will see that there is no magic under the hood, you probably can't see the implementation of the actual apple build in delegate methods but I assure you that there is a lot of logic implemented in those but it's just not available for privacy reasons I assume.
When you create your custom delegate let's say for example...

You have Class A and in this class, you start by creating a protocol

```
protocol ClassADelegate: class {
func changeBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor?)
}
```

In this class you have a delegate property like this.

```
weak var delegate: ClassADelegate?
```

Let's say that this class is a Viewcontroller and you have an IBACtion on it like a UIbutton, and your goal is that when you tap that button another ViewController in your app change its background color to blue. Inside this action in Class A you do this...

```
func someAction() {
 delegate?.changeBackgroundColor(.blue)
}
```

,
Let's say that the "magic" happens here in class A, by the way if you are thinking in delegates using UITableview think that UItableView is class A.

ok so now you have Class B that is where you want to change the color right?
Well now class B needs to conform to the protocol like this, just like you also conform to the protocol UITableViewDelegate etc.

```
class ClassB: UIViewController, ClassADelegate {
}
```

Now think of the word delegate for a second and think what that means, you are just delegating responsibility to somebody else, right? and yes, in this case, ClassB is going to be the delegated, for that we need to have an instance of Class A in class B just to have access to it's delegate property.

```
let classa = ClassA()
classa.delegate = self
```

the final step is just to call the method of the protocol like this..

```
func changeBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor?) {
view.backgroundColor = color
}
```

To conclude if yo see this method in your class but you don't have access to the implementation of the protocol, you will ask yourself "where does this magic color coming from??" but as you saw it just comes from another class where a protocol belongs to, hope this helps.